# get financial data using Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have managed to write some Python code and Selenium that navigates to a webpage that contains financial data that is in some tables.

I want to be able to extract the data and put it into excel.

The tables seem to be html based tables code below:

```
                <tr>
                <td class="bc2T bc2gt">Last update</td>
                <td class="bc2V bc2D">03/15/2018</td><td class="bc2V bc2D">03/14/2019</td><td class="bc2V bc2D">03/12/2020</td><td class="bc2V bc2D" style="background-color:#DEFEFE;">05/22/2020</td><td class="bc2V bc2D" style="background-color:#DEFEFE;">05/20/2020</td><td class="bc2V bc2D" style="background-color:#DEFEFE;">05/18/2020</td> 
            </tr>
    </table>
```

The table has the following class name:
`<table class='BordCollapseYear2' style="margin-right:20px; font-size:12px; width:100%;" cellspacing=0>`

Is there a way I can extract this data? Ideally I want this to be dynamic so that it can extract information for different companies.

I've never used it before, but I've seen BeautifulSoup library mentioned a few times.

https://www.marketscreener.com/MICROSOFT-CORPORATION-4835/financials/

As an example Microsoft. I'd want to extract the income statement data, balance sheet etc.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the page?

Comment: What is it your trying to extract ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely added a link and more detail of what I'd want to extract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will scrape all tables found on the page and pretty prints them:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.marketscreener.com/MICROSOFT-CORPORATION-4835/financials/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = {}
# for every table found on page...
for table in soup.select('table.BordCollapseYear2'):
    table_name = table.find_previous('b').text
    all_data[table_name] = []
    # ..scrape every row
    for tr in table.select('tr'):
        row = [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for td in tr.select('td')]
        if len(row) == 7:
            all_data[table_name].append(row)

#pretty print all data:
for k, v in all_data.items():
    print('Table name: {}'.format(k))
    print('-' * 160)
    for row in v:
        print(('{:<25}'*7).format(*row))
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Table name: Valuation
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fiscal Period: June      2017                     2018                     2019                     2020                     2021                     2022                     
Capitalization 1         532 175                  757 640                  1 026 511                1 391 637                -                        -                        
Entreprise Value (EV) 1  485 388                  700 112                  964 870                  1 315 823                1 299 246                1 276 659                
P/E ratio                25,4x                    46,3x                    26,5x                    32,3x                    29,7x                    25,8x                    
Yield                    2,26%                    1,70%                    1,37%                    1,10%                    1,18%                    1,31%                    
Capitalization / Revenue 5,51x                    6,87x                    8,16x                    9,81x                    8,89x                    7,95x                    
EV / Revenue             5,02x                    6,34x                    7,67x                    9,28x                    8,30x                    7,30x                    
EV / EBITDA              12,7x                    15,4x                    17,7x                    20,2x                    18,3x                    15,9x                    
Cours sur Actif net      7,46x                    9,15x                    10,0x                    12,1x                    10,1x                    8,49x                    
Nbr of stocks (in thousands)7 720 510                7 683 198                7 662 818                7 583 440                -                        -                        
Reference price (USD)    68,9                     98,6                     134                      184                      184                      184                      
Last update              07/20/2017               07/19/2018               07/18/2019               05/08/2020               04/30/2020               04/30/2020               

Table name: Annual Income Statement Data
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fiscal Period: June      2017                     2018                     2019                     2020                     2021                     2022                     
Net sales 1              96 657                   110 360                  125 843                  141 818                  156 534                  174 945                  
EBITDA 1                 38 117                   45 319                   54 641                   65 074                   70 966                   80 445                   
Operating profit (EBIT) 129 339                   35 058                   42 959                   52 544                   57 045                   65 289                   
Operating Margin         30,4%                    31,8%                    34,1%                    37,1%                    36,4%                    37,3%                    
Pre-Tax Profit (EBT) 1   23 149                   36 474                   43 688                   52 521                   57 042                   65 225                   
Net income 1             21 204                   16 571                   39 240                   43 693                   47 223                   53 905                   
Net margin               21,9%                    15,0%                    31,2%                    30,8%                    30,2%                    30,8%                    
EPS 2                    2,71                     2,13                     5,06                     5,68                     6,18                     7,11                     
Dividend per Share 2     1,56                     1,68                     1,84                     2,02                     2,16                     2,41                     
Last update              07/20/2017               07/19/2018               07/18/2019               05/22/2020               05/22/2020               05/22/2020               

Table name: Balance Sheet Analysis
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fiscal Period: June      2017                     2018                     2019                     2020                     2021                     2022                     
Net Debt 1               -                        -                        -                        -                        -                        -                        
Net Cash position 1      46 787                   57 528                   61 641                   75 814                   92 392                   114 978                  
Leverage (Debt / EBITDA) -1,23x                   -1,27x                   -1,13x                   -1,17x                   -1,30x                   -1,43x                   
Free Cash Flow 1         31 378                   32 252                   38 260                   41 953                   46 887                   53 155                   
ROE (Net Profit / Equities)29,4%                    19,4%                    42,4%                    36,6%                    34,5%                    36,1%                    
Shareholders' equity 1   72 195                   85 215                   92 524                   119 417                  136 690                  149 484                  
ROA (Net Profit / Asset) 9,76%                    6,51%                    14,4%                    18,5%                    14,6%                    14,7%                    
Assets 1                 217 276                  254 580                  272 703                  235 800                  323 445                  366 702                  
Book Value Per Share 2   9,24                     10,8                     13,4                     15,2                     18,2                     21,6                     
Cash Flow per Share 2    5,04                     5,63                     6,73                     7,03                     8,02                     9,79                     
Capex 1                  8 129                    11 632                   13 925                   15 698                   17 922                   19 507                   
Capex / Sales            8,41%                    10,5%                    11,1%                    11,1%                    11,4%                    11,2%                    
Last update              07/20/2017               07/19/2018               07/18/2019               05/22/2020               05/22/2020               05/04/2020
```

EDIT (to save `all_data` as csv file):

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for k, v in all_data.items():
        spamwriter.writerow([k])
        for row in v:
            spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

Screenshot from LibreOffice:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I could get it to put the data into Excel instead of printing to the terminal?

Comment: I tried using the csv code that you provided but it doesn't seem to do anything, I've put that block of code after the code that prints to the command line. Would that be correct?

Comment: @Mathlearner Yes, that's correct. If there's data in variable `all_data` (you can check if there's something printed on the screen), then it saves the data into `data.csv` file.

Comment: ah yes! It's just in some weird location on my PC.Thanks so much!